# iFrame is not working in Chrome

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to get an iFrame to work in Chrome. I Submit the src url via a form.

Instead of the requested website however I just receive an error message from chrome:

This web page is not available. 
The webpage at `http://www.google.com%22/` might be temporarily down or it might have moved permanently to a new web address.

I haven't actually added the %22/ to the address it adds that to the end of everything I submit with the form.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a code specific problem.  Can you post the form?  HTML (and any javascript that may be relevant) should be fine by the sound of it.

Comment: Oh, and %22 is a double quote (") ... is it possible you've left one in code/javascript somewhere where it's not needed?

Comment: You were right, I totally missed that extra double quote. Where did you find out what %22 meant? Also, that was a legitimate answer to my question, I would mark it as the answer if I could!

Answer (score 0):

The %22 is a double quote (") ... is it possible you've left one in code/javascript somewhere where it is not needed.